# Why Google File System divide files into Chunks with 64 MB？

Tags: cloud, distributed-computing, gfs

Is there any reasons for dividing into 64 MB? And they divide each chunk as 64 KB blocks .Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are. You should check [this document](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/es-419//archive/gfs-sosp2003.pdf) on Google File System. See 2.5 Chunk Size